# php libpq postgres version

Tags: php, postgresql, php-pgsql

I have PHP Version 5.6.29 with pgsql PostgreSQL Support enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   9.2.18. Working Ok!

I added new version of postgresql server (9.6) (from postgres repos with yum) in another port works correctly too, Now, How can I do whit php to work with this new version? phpinfo() shows that keep working with 9.2.
Thank you in advance and sorry for my english.

Guillermo

Comment: For most simple purposes, you can keep using the old libpq just fine on the new server.

Comment: ... and if you *really* need a more current libpq, you'll probably have to build PHP yourself.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz, Is there any guide to re-compile php with a particular version of postgres libpq?

Comment: Thank you Craig, jaja, but it makes me a little noise in my head to have the latest version installed and that php is connected with an old library.
Yesterday I uninstalled 9.2 version but phpinfo still reports that it connects to postgres with "PostgreSQL (libpq) PostgreSQL 9.2.18 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5 -11), 64-bit "

Comment: @user2144831 Did u got solution for this? Plz somebody Reply

Comment: the post is from 2017!, now is ``March 2021`` !! I have ``PHP 8`` and this come with ``libpq Version    9.6.5`` why this obsolete version in PHP 8??, how fixed/update?